# Installing Pandoc on Azure Platform (watson-developer-cloud)

Tags: python, azure, pip, watson

I am trying to deploy a Python web app to Azure. The app uses the watson-developer-cloud package. I have added it to the requirements.txt file in the app root directory. However, when running git push azure master, the deployment fails with the following message:

```
remote: Collecting watson-developer-cloud (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
remote:   Using cached watson-developer-cloud-1.2.0.tar.gz
remote:     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:     See http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html
remote:     for installation options
remote:     ---------------------------------------------------------------
remote:     
remote:     Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:       File "D:\local\Temp\pip-build-31h4r4ki\watson-developer-cloud\setup.py", line 72, in <module>
remote:         long_description=read_md('README.md'),
remote:       File "D:\local\Temp\pip-build-31h4r4ki\watson-developer-cloud\setup.py", line 39, in read_md
remote:         return convert(f, 'rst')
remote:       File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\pypandoc\__init__.py", line 69, in convert
remote: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in D:\local\Temp\pip-build-31h4r4ki\watson-developer-cloud\
remote:         outputfile=outputfile, filters=filters)
remote:       File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\pypandoc\__init__.py", line 260, in _convert_input
remote:         _ensure_pandoc_path()
remote:       File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\pypandoc\__init__.py", line 544, in _ensure_pandoc_path
remote:         raise OSError("No pandoc was found: either install pandoc and add it\n"
remote:     OSError: No pandoc was found: either install pandoc and add it
remote:     to your PATH or or call pypandoc.download_pandoc(...) or
remote:     install pypandoc wheels with included pandoc.
remote:     
remote:     ----------------------------------------
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote: 
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.
```

How could I install Pandoc? I have tried to do so through the Kudu Debug CMD console, but it outputs 'Access Denied' errors.

Answer (score 0):

choco install [pandoc](https://chocolatey.org/packages/pandoc), e.g. Or maybe using [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pandoc.Windows/).